# Query in hibernate hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, extjs

Table structure

Table1

```
ID   Name Type Parentid
123  s     a       124
124  r     b       125
125  t     a       123
```

If the type is `a`, I should get the parent `id` and `get` the name of that parent id.

How to write the query in hibernate hbm.xml file.. 
SO that i can map in the mapping bean and display it in frontend. I am using ExtJS `grid` as frontend and `POstgres` as backend.

Please help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What should the query find? What are the parameters of the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct parent.name FROM Parent parent WHERE parent.id in (SELECT table1.Parentid FROM Table1 table1 WHERE table1.Type = 'a');
```

With this query you'll find all parent names for all entities in table1 with type a.